# Salesforce : How do we block a User from using query with Rest API?

Tags: api, security, rest

We are integrating an External System (Drupal) with Salesforce . The corner case being , A user who may get access to the shell of the server the Drupal Instance is running , may have access to all of SF data which can be used to export all data .

How do we ensure "query" is restricted ?

Its my Understanding the "API Enableb" means , Query via Rest API is enabled too

Note : this User should be a super user with Sys Admin access to all data .
All we need is the ability to query removed .

---

Thanks to @identigral for the Answer pointing to Transaction Security

[image]

While I am able to Block Query on URL Level

When I use the Same Query as part of a Subrequest in
Composite API
{
"compositeRequest": [
{
"method": "POST",
"url": "/services/data/v57.0/sobjects/Account",
"referenceId": "refAccount",
"body": {
"Name": "Sample Account"
}
},
{
"method": "POST",
"url": "/services/data/v56.0/query/?q=SELECT+name+from+Account",
"referenceId": "refContact",
"body": {
"LastName": "Sample Contact",
"AccountId": "@{refAccount.id}"
}
}
]
}

[image]

### This by-passes the Transaction Security Policy .
Response

[image]
Please Help how this can be averted

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/enhanced_transaction_security/enhanced_transaction_security_basics

Comment: Thank you @identigral . This helped us block Query at the URL Level . 

However , We are still able to Query through Composite Requests .

Comment: Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. While we are able to block anyone using REST API Params in a URL . But does not block Composite API 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_batch.htm 


@identigral

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/enhanced_transaction_security/enhanced_transaction_security_basics: _API Event for monitoring and protecting all API queries_  Without a reproducible example, your claim that something doesn't work is difficult to evaluate.

Comment: I've edited the question for more clarity . Please let me know if elaborates my question @identigral

Comment: Could you show how composite query will _export all data_ ?

Comment: I have added the response . As you can see , there is a facility to "Query" with ANY SOQL query . @identigral which makes it vurnerable

Comment: There is a facility but in case of a composite query it's limited in how much it brings back, it will not "export all data". In addition to this, real-world threat mitigation does not rely on a single feature in a single product.  https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/privileged-user-responsibilities is a good read.

Comment: Its been confirmed from Salesforce Support that this is indeed a bug and they are working it . Thanks for pointing me to the solution to begin with @identigral